# Errors when including simple component into App (react/redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux, react-slingshot

I've got a boilerplate based on https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/. I've removed the FuelSavings app and replaced it with one that works OK - but I wrote a component, and when I include it under the App, it prevents anything from rendering (I get a white page).

I'm getting 3 errors when I add in the `<UserHeader />` tag into App.js:

- "Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `App`."
- Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `App`.
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

If I remove the `UserHeader` tag, the rest of the page loads just fine.

src/components/App.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';
import { UserHeader } from './UserHeader';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <IndexLink to="/">Home</IndexLink> | <Link to="/About">About</Link>
      <UserHeader />

      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

src/components/UserHeader.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

const UserHeader = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>Welcome!</p>
    );
};

export default UserHeader;
```

Any thoughts welcomed. The server itself shows *no* problems at all, just a warning about missing the props validation. The issue is preventing any code in `UserHeader` from executing. I'm just not experienced enough to know how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

`import { UserHeader } from './UserHeader'`

should be:

`import UserHeader from './UserHeader'`

because `UserHeader` is the default export.

Comment: That was it!! Thanks!